# Kohana3 framework: MVC: call function from View

Tags: php, foreach, scope, kohana-3

The controller passes `$results` to the View. 
The View has:

```
<?php foreach ($results as $result): ?>
<?php echo $result->time_start.' '.$result->time_finished;?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Also, I would like to display the difference  (`$result->time_finished` minus `$result->time_start`) in format `hh:mm:ss` for each $result. If mm<10, then zero is shown, so 63 seconds are displayed as 00:01:03, not as 0:1:3.

Should I do all this staff in the view?
I believe it makes sense to use a function. Should I write this function in the model and call it from the view?

If not foreach, I would definitely call fhe function from the controller and pass the proper hh:mm:ss to the view from the controller.
But, what should I do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a function that you need to use multiple times in your code, it makes sense to 1. create your own helper or 2. extend Kohana's build in Date helper. Helpers are used for this kind of operations, not the Model and if the code gets to complex, also not the view.

I don't know if you use Kohana 3.2 or 3.3, but there is a bit of a difference in naming convention between them (since 3.3 PSR-0 is implemented which means capitalized file and class names), but here are the DOCS for helpers:

http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/helpers

http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/helpers

and for extending existing classes:

http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/files

http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/files

I provide the answer if you use Kohana 3.2:

Solution 1: It would make sense to extend the Kohana Date class. Create a file named date.php in application/classes. The file should look like this:

```
class Date extends Kohana_Date {
  public static function some_function_to_convert($date1, $date2) { } ;
}
```

In your view do this: `Date::some_function_to_convert($date1, $date2);`

Solution 2: Create your own helper in application/classes/helper dir. Name it date_conversion.php. Your file then looks like this:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class helper_date_conversion {
  public static function some_function_to_convert($date1, $date2) { } ;
}
```

In your view do this:

```
helper_date_conversion::some_function_to_convert($date1, $date2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I would do:
I would write a static function for formatting your dates (either using my own class or extending Kohana `Date` class).
I would use this function in your view directly:

```
<?php echo SomeClass::date_format($result->time_start, $result->time_finished) ?>
```

Why in the view? Because the function is used for formatting, it doesn't actually return different data set.